# Extract Google Slide numbers in presenter view from div which requires dropdown to be open before they load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to extract the Slide numbers from Google Slide Presenter View.

They all get listed under `goog-menuitem-checkbox` but only when once clicked on the slide selection dropdown.

Is there any way I could trigger this with javascript to already load them so i can extract them?

**Drop down when presenter view is loaded**

```
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-activedescendant=":2p" style="user-select: none;"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" id=":2p" role="option" aria-selected="true" aria-setsize="19" aria-posinset="1">Slide 1 </div><div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

**Dropdown when clicked/opened**

```
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" style="user-select: none;" aria-activedescendant=":2p"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" id=":2p" role="option" aria-selected="true" aria-setsize="19" aria-posinset="1">Slide 1 </div><div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</div></div>

console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('goog-menuitem-checkbox')[0].nextSibling.data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's interesting that I came across this exact problem while trying to [extract published google slides](https://aijayvishnu.medium.com/how-to-download-google-slide-presentations-published-to-the-web-3c1564bd92c1), so I can share what I used.

You don't actually need to trigger open the slide selection menu, the html of the div itself has two attributes for the same:

- **aria-posinset** : For Current Slide Index
- **aria-setsize** : For Total Slides count in the presentation

Reading it something like this should get you what you need:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class$="-caption"]')[0].getAttribute("aria-setsize")
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks for sharing, indeed `console.log("Slide",document.querySelectorAll('[class$="-caption"]')[0].getAttribute("aria-posinset"),"of", document.querySelectorAll('[class$="-caption"]')[0].getAttribute("aria-setsize"));` outputs Slide X of Y. Now I don't need to extract the individual slides given I get the total slides, brilliant. Just wondering why its getAttribute `aria-posinset` when in the object is stored under `ariaPosInSet` ? `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[class$="-caption"]')[0].ariaPosInSet);` (I noticed it also outputs "undefined".

Comment: Just noticed this doesn't work on Slide Edit view, as it always returns total slides 16. Might you have come across how to get the total slides in edit mode?

Comment: and even better would be retrieving current selected slide in active mode vs total. Did you come across some more info on this? Thanks @loxxy

Comment: FYI - I managed to inspect the slide selected in Editor view on the right as well as utilise the "total slides" hover info during scrolling to extract this info: Current selected slide:
`document.getElementsByClassName("punch-filmstrip-selected-thumbnail-pagenumber")[0].innerHTML;`

total slides: 
`console.log(document.getElementById("punch-total-slide-count").innerHTML.replace(/ total slides/, ''));`

Comment: just realised this only works when slides thumbnails are scrolled down, need to find a way to either trigger scroll down so that info is auto-populated  or if there is another way to trigger it.